# Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '() -> Void'

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct TrainingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = ViewModel()
    @State var name = ""
    @State var description = ""
    @State var duration = ""
    @State var availableSeats = ""
    @State var place = ""
    @State var startTime = ""
    @State var image = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(model.list) { item in
            Text("\(item.availableSeats)")
        }
            Divider()
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
            TextField("Place", text: $place)
            TextField("StartTime", text: $startTime)
            TextField("Image", text: $image)
            TextField("Description", text: $description)
            TextField("Duration", text: $duration)
            TextField("Available Seats", text: $availableSeats)
            Button(action:
                    model.addData(availableSeats: availableSeats, image: image, description: description, duration: duration, name: name, place: place, startTime: startTime).   // Here the error appears!!!
            ) { Text("Save")  }
        }
    }
    init() {
        model.getData()
    }
    }

 struct TrainingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
     static var previews: some View{
         TrainingView()
     }
 }
```

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

struct TrainingsSchedule: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var availableSeats: String
    var image: String
    var description: String
    var duration: String
    var name: String
    var place: String
    var startTime: String
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list = [TrainingsSchedule]()
    
    func deleteData(trainingScheduleToDelete: TrainingsSchedule) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("trainingSchedule").document(trainingScheduleToDelete.id).delete { error in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.list.removeAll { trainingSchedule in
                        return trainingSchedule.id == trainingScheduleToDelete.id
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addData(availableSeats: String, image: String, description: String, duration: String, name: String, place: String, startTime: String){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("trainingSchedule").addDocument(data: ["availableSeats" : availableSeats, "image" : image, "description" : description, "duration" : duration, "name" : name, "place" : place, "startTime" : startTime]) { error in
            if error == nil {
                self.getData()
            }
            else {
                //Handle the error
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func getData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("trainingSchedule").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if error == nil {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.list = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                            return TrainingsSchedule(id: d.documentID,
                                                     availableSeats: d["availableSeats"] as? String ?? "",
                                                     image: d["image"] as? String ?? "",
                                                     description: d["description"] as? String ?? "",
                                                     duration: d["duration"] as? String ?? ""
                                                     , name: d["name"] as? String ?? ""
                                                     , place: d["place"] as? String ?? ""
                                                     , startTime: d["startTime"] as? String ?? "")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                //Handle the error
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

I want to receive data by entering it in a text field through firestore

All my data in firestore corresponds to values and data types. The get data function worked without problems, but the add function throws the above error

I think I'm missing something but checked several times and can't find my mistake

Comment: Which add function  - the `func addData` or when it's called `model.addData`? On what line are you getting that error? There''s also an extraneous period "." in this call `.addData(availableSeats: availableSeats, image: image, description: description, duration: duration, name: name, place: place, startTime: startTime).` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Youre passing a function to something that is expecting a block.

Try this:

```
Button(“Save”) {
                    model.addData(availableSeats: availableSeats, image: image, description: description, duration: duration, name: name, place: place, startTime: startTime) // Here the error appears!!! }
```